# Regular Expression over a file path to match file names that don't start with some word

Tags: python, regex

In a text containing lines with full paths, I need to match only lines whose **file name** doesn't start with the word **'TMP'** (case insensitive).

In the next sample list, lines marked with "EXCLUDE" shouldn't be matched.

```
c:\folder1\TMP_file.ext----------EXCLUDE
c:\TMP_folder1\file.ext
c:\folder1\TMP_folder2\file.ext
c:\folder1/TMP_file.ext----------EXCLUDE
c:\file.ext
c:\TMP_file.ext------------------EXCLUDE
TMP_file.ext---------------------EXCLUDE
file.ext
```

I came up with the simple expression `[^\\/\r\n]+$` (accepting **'\'** and **'/'** as directory separators) that successfully matches whole file names with their extensions, but I can't figure out how to add `(?!...)` to exclude the matches that start with 'tmp'.

Inverting the expression `tmp[^\\/\r\n]+$` would be also the solution, but I don't know how.

I know this question is similar to others (taking the risk of a downvote...) but I didn't found a way to connect them with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?i)^(?!(?:.*[/\\])?TMP(?![^\W_])[^/]*$).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b2KfB8/2) (`[^/]` is replaced with `[^/\n]` since the regex is tested against a single multiline string).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:.*[/\\])?TMP(?![^\W_])[^/]*$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is

  - `(?:.*[/\\])?` - an optional occurrence of any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then `/` or `\`
  - `TMP(?![^\W_])` - `TMP` (case insensitive) not followed with a letter or digit (can be followed with `_`)
  - `[^/]*` - any 0 or more chars other than  `/`
  - `$` - end of string.
- `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the right solution here. You better iterate over file names, takes the base path, and skip if it startswith 'TMP'.

```
def filter_tmp(text):
    paths = text.split('\n')
    for p in paths:
        if not os.path.basename(p).startswith('TMP'):
            yield p
```

Then `list(filter_tmp(text))` would give you the list of non-temp paths.

Comment: Does it mean that RegEx can't recursively find new matches inside previously found  ones? I.e., if I successfully match file name in 'c:\folder1\TMP_file.ext', can't I run a new match expression ('TMP') inside that successful match? Could (?R) help?

Comment: No, I claim nothing here about what's impossible; the claim is about what is recommended and readable.